# Appoximation of Lipschitz functions by $C^1-$functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, approximation-theory, lipschitz-functions

I came across the following statements in a math book without proof.

Denote $M_k$ as the set of functions from $C[a,b]$ that is K-Lipschitz continous. i.e $\forall x,y,|f(x)-f(y)|\le K|x-y|$

1) The closure of $M_k$ is also $M_k$. (This I already have a proof.)

2) $M_k$ is also the closure of the set of differentiable functions that $\forall x,|f'(x)|\le K$. (This I don't know why)

It's clear that  $\{ f: |f'(x)|\le K \}$ is a subset of $M_k$.

What is not clear is that why $\forall f \in M_k$, $f$ would be a contact point of $\{ f: |f'(x)|\le K \}$. i.e. how to prove that every $f \in M_k$ counld be arbitary approximate by $f \in \{ f: |f'(x)|\le K \}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend $f$ to the whole real real line, so that $f(x)=f(a)$, for $x<a$ and $f(x)=f(b)$ for $x>b$. Next set
$$
f_\varepsilon(x)=\frac{1}{2\varepsilon}\int_{-\varepsilon}^\varepsilon f(x+t)\,dt.
$$
Then $f_\varepsilon\to f$ uniformly in $[a,b]$, as $\varepsilon\to 0$, as
$$
\lvert\, f_\varepsilon(x)-f(x)\rvert\le\frac{1}{2\varepsilon}\int_{-\varepsilon}^\varepsilon \lvert\,f(x+t)-f(x)\rvert\,dt\le\sup_{t\in [-\varepsilon,\varepsilon]}\lvert\,f(x+t)-f(x)\rvert,
$$
due to the uniform continuity of $f$ in $[a,b]$.

Next $f_\varepsilon$ is $k-$Lipschitz as
$$
\lvert\,f_\varepsilon(x)-f_\varepsilon(y)\rvert\le\frac{1}{2\varepsilon}\int_{-\varepsilon}^\varepsilon \lvert\,f(x+t)-f(y+t)\rvert\,dt\le k\lvert x-y\rvert,
$$
and finally $f_\varepsilon$ is differentiable since
$$
\frac{f_\varepsilon(x+h)-f_\varepsilon(x)}{h}=\frac{1}{2h\varepsilon}\left(
\int_{x+h-\varepsilon}^{x+h+\varepsilon} f(t)\,dt-\int_{x-\varepsilon}^{x+\varepsilon}f(t)\,dt\right)=\frac{1}{2h\varepsilon}
\left(\int_{x+\varepsilon}^{x+\varepsilon+h} f(t)\,dt-\int_{x-\varepsilon}^{x-\varepsilon+h}f(t)\,dt\right)\to \frac{1}{2\varepsilon}\big(f(x+\varepsilon)-f(x-\varepsilon)\big),
$$
as $h\to 0$.